# Repeating Regex for Redshift

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'd like to pull special characters (punctuation and emoji) from a column in my Redshift table. I've been testing out regex functions in this dynamic tester here:

http://regexr.com

This one works on the dynamic tester for pulling non-space characters: `[^a-zA-Z\s]`

However in Redshift it still pulls spaces and only pulls the FIRST special character, whether it's a question mark or an emoji.

According to Redshift documentation, it does support the regexp_substr function: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html

I have the following query in Redshift:

```
select
*
, regexp_substr(device_contact_name,'[^\sa-zA-Z]') as special_characters
from table
```

For example if the field has "Daniel!" it will return "!" but if the field has "Daniel !" it will return " "

If the field has "Daniel!!" I want the results to return "!!"

Thoughts on how to properly eliminate the space from the results and to return ALL special characters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It shouldn't return a space since that is not allowed by the regex. To get more than 1 at a time, quantify the class `[^\sa-zA-Z]+`

Comment: Remember that In _negated_ character classes, all items are separately as not-item, and each negation is _AND_ ed together.

Comment: Thanks everyone! NetMage's solution worked for the problem I was having: '[^\\sa-zA-Z]+'

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character is the default escape character, so you should double it:

```
select * , regexp_substr(device_contact_name,'[^\\sa-zA-Z]+') as special_characters from table
```

Comment: Thank you NetMage! The function you provided '[^\\sa-zA-Z]+' works perfectly for capturing all the special characters.